# Can't access array values outside of function - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to query my Parse database in order to search for a username and show all posts related to the username. The posts are split into two fields and I "paste" them back together inside the function.

```
    func searchDataBase() -> ([String]) {

    if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

        userHeading.text = username + "'s Profile"

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Wish")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo:username)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) wishes.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        //println(object.objectId)
                        var parseID = object.objectId!

                        var query = PFQuery(className:"Wish")
                        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(parseID) {
                            (detailedWish: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {

                                let partOne = detailedWish!["wishFieldOne"] as! String
                                let partTwo = detailedWish!["wishFieldTwo"] as! String

                                let fullWish = "I wish I " + partOne + " when I " + partTwo

                                self.wishes.append(fullWish)

                            } else {
                                println(error)
                            }


                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }


        }


    } else {
        println("No user logged in")
    }
    return wishes
}
```

After the function above runs, I want to place the user's posts inside a `UITableView`:

```
//TABLE VIEW FUNCTIONS

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    searchDataBase()

    return wishes.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = recentPosts.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    searchDataBase()

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = wishes[row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    recentPosts.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    searchDataBase()

    let row = indexPath.row
    println(wishes[row])
}
```

When I build the app the `UITableView` doesn't show the posts I queried in the `searchDataBase` function. If I `println(wishes)` immediately after the array is appended, it works, but when I print the array outside of the function it is empty. **How can I make the contents of the `wishes` array accessible outside the function - after the query is successful?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an odd approach. Your calling searchDataBase() on every tableView method. You surely dont want to make a call to parse every time? Also your searchDataBase() method doesnt need to return an array. You can simply just append the results to this array and reload your table when complete. Im assuming this would be a much better approach for you.

So, my solution to you would be to remove your searchDatabase() function call from all your tableView methods and to place it inside your viewDidLoad(). Also you should change you searchDataBase() to look like so

```
    func searchDataBase(){

    if let username = PFUser.currentUser()?.username {

        userHeading.text = username + "'s Profile"

        var query = PFQuery(className:"Wish")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo:username)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) wishes.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {
                        //println(object.objectId)
                        var parseID = object.objectId!

                        var query = PFQuery(className:"Wish")
                        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(parseID) {
                            (detailedWish: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {

                                let partOne = detailedWish!["wishFieldOne"] as! String
                                let partTwo = detailedWish!["wishFieldTwo"] as! String

                                let fullWish = "I wish I " + partOne + " when I " + partTwo

                                self.wishes.append(fullWish)

                            } else {
                                println(error)
                            }


                        }

                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData() // <- This will populate your tableView with your wishes
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }


        }


    } else {
        println("No user logged in")
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I had to move `self.tableView.reloadData()` right below the `self.wishes.append(fullWish)` line, your code worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah yes, Good point. I had a refresh being called before the background query could finish. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

`searchDataBase()` performs the returns the array. Where's the variable `wishes` that you're accessing?

Instead:

```
let wishes = searchDataBase()
```

and then you'll have the array for your table view delegate functions.

Comment: That won't work because the searchDataBase function is using the Parse function `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId`, which is asynchronous. The results will not be available when searchDataBase returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to do that way.

What you need to do is to rewrite your `searchDataBase` method to take a completion closure as a parameter. Then in the completion block to your call to `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId`, build your result array and pass to the `searchDataBase` completion closure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with completion blocks - is there an article that would be applicable to my situation?